# How to Change a div from an ACE Editor back to a div

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I know that you can turn a div into an ACE editor like so:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
```

How does one change this back into a normal div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`editor.destroy` doesn't remove all event listeners from div, so one have to do something like this.

```
var value = editor.getValue()
editor.destroy()
var oldDiv = editor.container
var newDiv = oldDiv.cloneNode(false)
newDiv.textContent = value
oldDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, oldDiv)
```